# How to solve this puzzle?

Tags: cipher, pattern, sudoku

[image: Image with question]

I have solved the sudoku. Scratching my head on the second part. Any hints?
It is not picked from any competition. One of my office colleagues usually post these types of puzzles on emails for fun which are quite hard to crack.

Comment: All of the empty cells line up with letters or 0s that all could be hexadecimal, though I'm not sure what to do with them after that.